# language file in codeigniter changed after login again

Tags: codeigniter

at the login (auth-Controller) i add some languagefiles into my session by using a helper function

call the Helper function in auth controller

```
if(!load_modul_languagefile($mod['controller_name'],$mod['systemmodul'])){ echo"langfile error: ".$mod['controller_name'].",".$mod['systemmodul']; }
```

This is the helper function

```
if (!function_exists('load_modul_languagefile')) 
    {
        function load_modul_languagefile($modulname,$systemmodul=false){
            
            $ci =& get_instance();
            if($systemmodul===false)
            {                
                $ci->db->select('systemmodul');
                $ci->db->from('table');
                $ci->db->where('controller_name',$modulname);
                $query=$ci->db->get();
                if($query->num_rows()>0){ $systemmodul=1; }
            }

            if($systemmodul==1){   $modulname='sysfile';  }
            
            //make sure the lang file already exists before including
            $lang=$ci->config->item('language');
            if(file_exists(APPPATH.'language/'.$lang.'/'.$modulname.'_lang.php'))
            {
                $ci =& get_instance();
                $ci->lang->load($modulname.'_lang',$lang);    
                return true;
            }
            else
            {   //may include a systemlog info
                echo"no file ->".APPPATH.'language/'.$lang.'/'.$modulname.'_lang.php'; 
                return false; 
            }     
        }
```

so afther do it into the auth-controller i check the result with

```
$all_lang_array=$this->lang->language;
echo"All lang array;<br>";
print_r( $all_lang_array);    
die("");
```

So all files are correctly loaded and the array has the content it should have.

Now after redirect to the subfolder views/mydestination this infos are no longer avivable.

if i try to get the same datas like in the auth (print_r like above in views/includes/_sidebar), i only recieve the content of the "fixfile"-languagfile. Alle other files are not loaded anymore.

I dont understand why the values of the language array will reduce now?

**Maybe there is a problem with the `$ci =& get_instance();` instance?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it seems, that i has figure out the way to do it.

I've change the position to load the language files from the auth-controller to the
core>my_controller

```
$langfiles=array('site');
$modules = get_all_modules(); 
                        foreach ($modules as $mod)
                        {   
                            if($mod['active']!=1 || $mod['systemmodul']==1){ continue; }

                        array_push($langfiles,$mod['controller_name']);

                    }
                    $this->lang->load($langfiles, $language);
```

for the moment it seems to work fine